# How do I change an array used from main

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to initialize an array and then, with another class (arrayCreation), change the size and elements of the array. However, I have no idea how it can be done, because all I get is a single element, as it is initialized in size and it is a 0, which is by default.

```
public class sort {
    public static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 1;
        int[] array = new int[size];
        initialMenuSelector(array,size);
    }

    public static void initialMenuRender(){
        System.out.println("Main menu:");
        System.out.println("1. Work with numbers");
        System.out.println("2. Work with words");
        System.out.println("3. Exit");
    }

    public static void initialMenuSelector(int[] array,int size){
        initialMenuRender();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
        int selector = scanner.nextInt();

        switch(selector){
            case 3:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Exiting...");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Work with words");
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Work with numbers");
                arrayCreation.arrayNumberCreation(array,size);
                arrayRender(array);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Invalid selection");
                initialMenuSelector(array,size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `System.out.println("")` can be replaced with `System.out.println()`. Also note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign your return value from array creation back to your initial array. When you pass a variable to a method in java, the variable is actually copied to a new local value. So after changing the array you have to then return it from the the function and assign it. So it should be like this.

```
array = arrayCreation.arrayNumberCreation(array,size);
```

Also array sizes cant be changed, so you have to create a new one and replace it with your old one. Don't know if you are doing that in array creation.

Answer (score 0):

In java the arrays aren't dynamic. What it means is that you want to change the size you need to create a new array with the new size and then copy each element you have on the old array. Or you can use an ArrayList if you don't want to manually resize the array

Answer (score 0):

create a new array with the size you want to increase.
for example, 
you have

```
old_array = new array[10];
```

and now you want to increase the size of this array 
copy the old values to the new one and replace the old one with the new one

```
new_array = new Array[20];
copy(new_array,old_array);
old_array = new_array
```

it's that easy